# SVG is not displaying in the mobile

Tags: svg

I have written an SVG code, it is working perfectly on the desktop, but not working on mobile devices. I also have referred to the previous SVG questions, but they are not helpful

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="11565.35433070866" height="4006.2992125984247" viewBox="0 0 11565.35433070866 4006.2992125984247" overflow="hidden" id="svgcontent" style="">
   <g>
      <title>background</title>
      <rect fill="#FFF" id="canvas_background" stroke-width="0" height="4006.29921" width="11565.35433" y="0" x="0"></rect>
   </g>
   <g>
      <title>Layer 1</title>
      <image x="16.33879" y="5.77534" width="11532.67714" height="3994.74844" preserveAspectRatio="none" id="svg_2" orighref="path/to/img" templatesrc="path/to/img" xlink:href="path/to/img" origwidth="16626" origheight="5759" lock="true"></image>
      <g label="Age" max-char="2" isrequired="true" yscale="1" xscale="1" elembboxheight="2253.91772" elembboxwidth="1446.53174" shapeval="0" shapeid="0" lineheight="1" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" text-anchor="start" fill="ee3b25" font-family="Gogono Cocoa Mochi" font-size="3000" text="3" type="text" id="svg_4">
         <path d="m7308.22719,2397.90878c100,33.33333 108.33333,158.33333 166.66667,241.66667c233.33333,50 316.66667,-216.66667 141.66667,-308.33333c-141.66667,-8.33333 -275,-41.66667 -391.66667,-83.33333c-50,-116.66667 -66.66667,-225 -41.66667,-325c116.66667,-50 241.66667,-83.33333 375,-91.66667c108.33333,-100 116.66667,-250 58.33333,-383.33333c-66.66667,-58.33333 -225,-41.66667 -191.66667,66.66667c100,308.33333 -458.33333,375 -566.66667,116.66667c-300,-700 825,-1008.33333 1233.33333,-475c108.33333,141.66667 183.33333,333.33333 150,583.33333c-16.66667,125 -133.33333,250 -316.66667,375c208.33333,83.33333 358.33333,241.66667 325,541.66667c-50,500 -875,625 -1266.66667,316.66667c-108.33333,-158.33333 -225,-341.66667 -133.33333,-541.66667c58.33333,-16.66667 208.33333,-33.33333 458.33333,-33.33333c0,0 0,0 0,0" stroke-width="0" fill="#ee3b25" id="svg_5"></path>
         <rect opacity="0" fill="#ee3b25" height="2253.91748" width="1446.53125" y="886.26029" x="6808.00671" id="svg_6"></rect>
      </g>
   </g>
</svg>
```

[image: output]

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"?

Comment: Is this SVG embedded in a HTML document or are you loading it as an independent document?

Comment: @Sean It is not displaying

Comment: @chrwahl It is an SVG embedded in HTML Document

Answer (score 1):

It is actually displaying but to to your pretty **large width and height** values, you will need to scroll for some minutes ...

Just remove them and make sure your svg has an appropriate width like 100% (default)

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 11565.35433070866 4006.2992125984247" overflow="hidden" id="svgcontent" style="">
   <g>
      <title>background</title>
      <rect fill="#FFF" id="canvas_background" stroke-width="0" height="4006.29921" width="11565.35433" y="0" x="0"></rect>
   </g>
   <g>
      <title>Layer 1</title>
      <image x="16.33879" y="5.77534" width="11532.67714" height="3994.74844" preserveAspectRatio="none" id="svg_2" orighref="path/to/img" templatesrc="path/to/img" xlink:href="path/to/img" origwidth="16626" origheight="5759" lock="true"></image>
      <g label="Age" max-char="2" isrequired="true" yscale="1" xscale="1" elembboxheight="2253.91772" elembboxwidth="1446.53174" shapeval="0" shapeid="0" lineheight="1" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" text-anchor="start" fill="ee3b25" font-family="Gogono Cocoa Mochi" font-size="3000" text="3" type="text" id="svg_4">
         <path d="m7308.22719,2397.90878c100,33.33333 108.33333,158.33333 166.66667,241.66667c233.33333,50 316.66667,-216.66667 141.66667,-308.33333c-141.66667,-8.33333 -275,-41.66667 -391.66667,-83.33333c-50,-116.66667 -66.66667,-225 -41.66667,-325c116.66667,-50 241.66667,-83.33333 375,-91.66667c108.33333,-100 116.66667,-250 58.33333,-383.33333c-66.66667,-58.33333 -225,-41.66667 -191.66667,66.66667c100,308.33333 -458.33333,375 -566.66667,116.66667c-300,-700 825,-1008.33333 1233.33333,-475c108.33333,141.66667 183.33333,333.33333 150,583.33333c-16.66667,125 -133.33333,250 -316.66667,375c208.33333,83.33333 358.33333,241.66667 325,541.66667c-50,500 -875,625 -1266.66667,316.66667c-108.33333,-158.33333 -225,-341.66667 -133.33333,-541.66667c58.33333,-16.66667 208.33333,-33.33333 458.33333,-33.33333c0,0 0,0 0,0" stroke-width="0" fill="#ee3b25" id="svg_5"></path>
         <rect opacity="0" fill="#ee3b25" height="2253.91748" width="1446.53125" y="886.26029" x="6808.00671" id="svg_6"></rect>
      </g>
   </g>
</svg>
```

### SVG limits for coordinates

You should also consider to round the coordinates number precision to avoid issues. Still OK in your example, but your drawing app or source seems to produce rather large numbers.
[The Limits of Numbers in SVG](https://oreillymedia.github.io/Using_SVG/extras/ch08-precision.html)

### Edit: issue with image element:

Try to rewrite you image element like this:

```
  <image  width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none" id="svg_2" orighref="path/to/img" templatesrc="path/to/img" href="https://picsum.photos/200/300" origwidth="16626" origheight="5759" lock="true" />
```

`<image>` is no self contained – so there is no closing `</image>` tag.
I also replace the deprecated xlink:href with `href`

Comment: Hi, can you point out which exact values did you changed, because after changing height and width it did not reflect

Comment: @Yash Karanke: Just remove  the svg's  width="11565.35433070866" and height – that's all

Comment: It did not worked

Comment: @Yash Karanke: Can you see the snippet above on your mobile device? Here is also a [codepen](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/gOXWLPx). It is working on my iOs safari. It might also be related to your global css.

Comment: I tested on iOS safari/Chrome/Moz but this particular issue is in Chrome Android

Comment: @Yash Karanke: can you provide a screenshot? Do you see a blank page? Is there a scrollable overflow?

Comment: I have added a screenshot An image should appear behind the `name`

Comment: Your updated answer works somewhat but it is not working in my image URL, my image itself is 6MB, what do you think is the issue?